# How do I get a field from a JSON returned by Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powerbi-rest-api

So, I have a code like the following.

```
$x = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'datasets/<dataset_id>/refreshes' -Method Get
```

When I run it, the returned JSON data is like this,

```
{
  "@odata.context":"<some_url>/myorg/$metadata#refreshes","value":[
    {
      ....
    },
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

But if I try to get the field `value`, by typing `$x.value`, I get nothing. What mistake am I doing. I am new to PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output was in string form. I had to first convert it to JSON form by using the following command.

`$j = $x | ConvertFrom-Json`

Then I can see the value by typing `$j.value`